# How to decide if a given set is a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Could you tell me how to decide if a certain set is a manifold? I know there already is a similar question here, but there we have fairly "visualizable" sets: a hemisphere and a square.

What in general do we need to do when we are given a set like this:

$\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 25; x^2+y^2 \le 9\}$

or this

$\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 = 2; \ y + z = 2; x > 0; \ y > 0; \ z > 0 \}$?

I think we can calculate the rank of the matrix of partial derivatives, but I'm not exactly sure what to do.

Could you help me?

Comment: The first is closed and has non-zero volume in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (intersection of a closed ball with a closed solid cylinder) so cannot be a manifold, though it is a manifold with a boundary (as such, it is not smooth; it can only be $C^0$). The second is topologically an open interval embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so you only need to find one chart that covers the whole set.

Comment: Could you tell me how to find such a chart?

Comment: @Bilbo Visualize the second space. First note that the $x$ and $y$ form a quater-circle in the $xy$ plane and then what does the condition on $y$ and $z$ say?

Comment: I visualised the second set by considering it as an intersection of three sets: the cylinder $C=\{(x,y,z)~|~x^2+y^2=2\}$, the plane $\{(x,y,z)~|~y+z=2\}$ that is non-parallel to the straight lines of $C$, and the open positive "eighth"-space $\{(x,y,z)~|~z,y,z>0\}$. The first two give an ellipse embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the third truncates this into a certain quarter of itself and leaves open end-points, making it topologically an open interval. I'll leave you to figure out the details of its embedding.

Comment: @Stromael is that a theorem that a closed set of positive measure cannot be a manifold?

Comment: @Vishal It ought to be. :) I'd show the given example cannot be a manifold by the fact that arbitrary unions of open sets are always open, so no such union of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be the given set.

Comment: @Stromael But for a manifold, you do not need the charts to be open in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ but only in the manifold. Could you be more clear?

Comment: Let $M$ be the given set. $M$ contains at least one open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Hence, if $M$ is a manifold, the charts on $M$ must be invertibly and smoothly mappable to open sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$; said charts on $M$ must therefore be open sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$. No union of open sets can ever equal $M$, so $M$ cannot be a manifold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ and $N$ are manifolds, and $F: M \to N$ is a smooth map, then

**Theorem:** $F^{-1}(c)$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $dim(M)-dim(N)$ if $c$ is a regular value of $F$. $c$ is called regular value of $F$ if $F_{*,p}$ is surjective for every $p \in F^{-1}(c)$.

Now in second case, your $F$ is $F(x,y,z) = (x^{2}+y^{2}, y+z)$. What are $M$ and $N$?

I suggest that you search for constant rank theorem and regular level set theorem. The theorem I mentioned here is the regular level set theorem.

Comment: Yes, I agree. They can be visualized. The constant rank theorem says that if $\emptyset \neq U \in top \mathbb{K}^n$, $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^m$ class $C^k$ and there exists $d$ such that $\forall x \in U:$ rank of $d_xf = d$, then there exist $C^k - $diffeomorphisms: $u$ between a certain neighbourhood $ V \ni a \in U$ and an open ball $D^n$ ($0 \rightarrow a$) and $w$ between a certain neighbourhood $W \ni f(a)$ and $D^m$ ($b \rightarrow 0$) s.t. $f(V) \subset W, \ \ (w \circ f \circ u) = (x_1, ..., x_d,0,...,0), \ (x_1, ..., x_n) \in D^n$. How can I use it here?

Comment: First what are your $M$ and $N$ here? And what is the rank of the mappings at each point?

Comment: $M = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $N=\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: $M$ is not exactly what you wrote, but it will work too. And can you calculate the Jacobian and then the ranks? And also, what is $c$?

Comment: If $x=y=0$ the rank is $1$ and if $x \neq 0$ or $y \neq 0$, then the rank is $2$. What should $M$ be? Isn't $c = (x^2+y^2, y+z)$?

Comment: But you see that $x=y=0$ case does not arise. And $c$ is something in $mathbb{R}^{2}$ not a function. In your case, $c=(2,2)$.